# Override Ebean naming convention

Tags: playframework-2.0, ebean

In Play 2.0.2 I'm trying to use ebean as the ORM and migrate my existing model classes from play-1.2.4.
All my camelCase fields in the model classes are getting mapped to underscore columns in the database, which creates issues as the columns in the databse don't use underscores.

I've been looking at the ebean API docs: http://www.avaje.org/static/javadoc/pub/com/avaje/ebean/config/UnderscoreNamingConvention.html

The underscore naming convention is the default if none has been specified, and that is what seems to be happening in the EbeanPlugin in Play.
Is there a way I could override this default setting (within Play)?

I'd hate to have to annotate all my camelCase fields with @Column to get around this.

TIA.

Comment: Just suggestion: maybe it will be faster to manually change  structure of existing DB? It always better to stay with current conventions, than finding workarounds for them.

Comment: DB updates, not an option for me. The DB is not accessed solely from play. Current convention?

Answer (score 4):

Old question, but since I just figured out the answer, thought I'd share.

In the conf dir, create a file called 'ebean.properties'.  In that file, put...

ebean.namingconvention=com.avaje.ebean.config.MatchingNamingConvention

There are a number of config options you can set there.

Look at line 1405: http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.avaje/ebean/2.7.2/com/avaje/ebean/config/ServerConfig.java

Comment: Does this work with play 2.0.X? As after taking a peek at the play ebean plugin init code, it seemed to ignore any conf file. Though shall give it a try and update.

Comment: The ebean code itself looks.  It just tries to open "ebean.properties", so on Heroku I had to put the file in the app root, not conf dir.  It works, though.  I'm using play 2.1.1, but I assume play 2.0.x is similar enough.

Answer (score 0):

I think Ebean support this, but I'm not sure if this is supported well by Play Framework, have a look in their Google Group, and update your question when you have the answer obviously, because it is a interesting question, I think :-).

But, perhaps setting a configuration as follows in the `application.conf`:

```
ebean.namingConvention.sequenceFormat={table}{column}seq
```

Comment: This did not work for me. It failed to compile, complaining about looking for OBJECT not LIST. I tried putting the value in double quotes, but still got the same error. The ebean.properties method suggested by Kevin Galligan did work though.